# HtmlAgilitypack div node - how to inquire what is inside a div first, then parse based on that

Tags: vb.net, html-agility-pack

I do parsing of my vendors web sites to get current item prices. 
I am using vb.net and a windows desktop app I coded in visual studio 2015

One vender has recently changed the way they display prices
The item prices are inside a common main div.
But the prices can be inside a table or a simple div

I can easily scrape prices from the tables or the divs's but I need to select the way the price is displayed first and then send that to the proper parsing code

Notice in the html below that this is the main div for both pricing schemes

```
<div class="price" id="itemPrice12345">
  .. a table or a simple price div are here.
</div>
```

---

This is how the div looks when it contains a table

```
<div class="price" id="itemPrice12345">
<table class="bglt"><tbody>
<tr>
<td class="texttable" nowrap="">1 to 9</td>
<td class="texttable">$9.93</td>
</tr></tbody></table>
</div>
```

I parse the prices out of a table using this node selection code

```
Dim tables As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection
tables = WebPageDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[contains(@id,'itemPrice')]/div[1]/table")
```

Then I iterate through the table rows "./tr" and table columns "./td" to pick out the prices

---

The same main div without a table looks like this

```
<div class="price" id="itemPrice12345">
<div class="price firstprice">$3.50</div>   
</div>
```

I parse the price out of this simple div using this node selection code

```
Dim PriceNode As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection
PriceNode = WebPageDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[contains(@id,'itemPrice')]/div[1]/div")
ItemPrice = PriceNode(0).InnerText
```

---

My question is, how can I determine if the main item price div contains a table or a simple price div inside? 
Once I know that, I can send the parsing to the proper code section. 
So I guess I need to inquire what is inside the main div first, but I am not sure how to do that?
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting a single node first and see if it's something:

```
Dim _itemPriceSelector As String = "//*[contains(@id,'itemPrice')]/div[1]"
Dim _divSelector As String = _itemPriceSelector & "/div"
Dim _tableSelector As String = _itemPriceSelector & "/table"

If doesNodeExist(_tableSelector) Then

    Dim tables As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection
    tables = WebPageDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(_tableSelector )

ElseIf doesNodeExist(_divSelector) Then

    Dim PriceNode As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection
    PriceNode = WebPageDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(_divSelector)
    ItemPrice = PriceNode(0).InnerText

End If

Private Function doesNodeExist(selector) As Boolean
    If IsNothing(WebPageDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(selector)) Then
        Return False
    Else
        Return True
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Just ran into a snag parsing out the vendor page. 

This vendor is now adding other items to the bottom of the web page sort of like what Amazon does. 

CUSTOMERS WHO BOUGHT THIS ITEM ALSO BOUGHT.
item2 -  item3 - item4 - item5. 

These added items also have the same xpath selectors as the item I am trying to scrape prices from. 
The item I am interested in always appears above the other on the web page. 

Is there any way to determine the first position on a page that my selector appears and use that one only?

Comment: Try to find a parent element that has a unique identifier you can key on and add that to your selector.

Comment: Thanks for your help

The div right above the pricing area I want is this. 
<div class="pull-left pdp-full-width" id="pdp-price">  
This is the xpath for this div. 
//*[@id="pdp-price"]  

Then the pricing area I want is below the div above. 
Do I first search for the div above and then search within that div for the pricing? 
I am a bit confused on how to do that?

Comment: I think I figured it out. Search for the div above the item pricing section I want. Load that html into a single node variable. Then search for the item xpath within that single node.

Comment: I believe you can do it all in one selector using a double backslash // after the parent element...but if that doesn't work, your way works also.